# How would I simplify this PostgreSQL query (filtering by joined table)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a character (hasMany) movies relationship.

I want to filter my results by a character name and also a movie title. So I want to return all characters whose name is like 'Sam' and that character must   be in at least one movie in which the movie title is like 'Sam the Movie'. **I still want to have all the movies associated to the characters too**.

I'm just wondering if there was a better way to do this? Is it possible to get it in one query?

```
WITH t1 AS 
(SELECT c.id, c.name, array_agg(m.title) AS movie_titles FROM characters c
LEFT JOIN characters_movies cm ON cm.character_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN movies m ON m.id = cm.movie_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%Sam%'
GROUP BY c.id)

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE exists 
(SELECT * FROM unnest(movie_titles) AS title
WHERE name LIKE '%Sam the Movie%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one query it would be something like this (can't test without the ddl). Note how I joined movies twice using different aliasses. The join with `m` makes sure you have a match on the title. The second `am` is to get all titles. I'm pretty sure using `LEFT JOIN` is not needed to get the result you want so I used normal `JOIN` which tend to be more efficient.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, array_agg(am.title) AS movie_titles 
  FROM characters c
    JOIN characters_movies cm ON cm.character_id = c.id
    JOIN movies m ON (m.id = cm.movie_id AND m.name LIKE '%Sam the Movie%')
    JOIN characters_movies acm ON acm.character_id = c.id
    JOIN movies am ON (am.id = acm.movie_id)
WHERE c.name LIKE '%Sam%'
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: This query filters out the movies for me, which was the problem I was having before (getting the right characters but it removes all the movies that doesn't match the name). I did manage to get a solution by using your query though. Added an `AND` to the `WHERE` clause and then checked if the character id is in that same query. Not sure if that is even better than what I had previously, since I'm selecting from the same table twice.

Comment: @cdv, I overlooked I also needed to join `characters_movies` twice, I have updated the query in my answer.

Comment: Works now. Never would have thought to join on the junction table twice. Thanks!